# Catch error: An invalid form control with name is not focusable

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to catch error: An invalid form control with name is not focusable.

It occurs when I submit a form and there's a field required with display none;

I would like to get the field that is invalid and show in the screen.

I've tried to simulate submit button click like:

```
try {
    btn.click();
} catch (e) {
    [...]
}
```

But it doesn't enter on catch, even when logs show the error;

I've already tried both of codes:

```
window.onerror = function myErrorHandler(errorMsg, url, lineNumber) {
    alert("Error occured: " + errorMsg);//or any message
    return false;
}

window.addEventListener("error", function (e) {
    alert("Error occurred: " + e.error.message);
    return false;
 })
```

But it doesn't catch the error too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [An invalid form control with name='' is not focusable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22148080/an-invalid-form-control-with-name-is-not-focusable)

Comment: No, there is so much questions about this, but none answers what I need. They just describe the error and what's the cause. They say to remove the validator too, but that's not what I want.

I want to catch the error to get the field that is not displayed on screen and display it.

Comment: My guess is that this isn't an error that can be caught, because the source is not JavaScript It's a browser/validation error. But maybe someone else may have a solution for you.

Answer (score -1):

[Caio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10321196/caio-kretzer)

I've stumbled across your post looking for the same answer.

Currently I'm working to implement a solution similar to this by hooking into the validation event:

[HTML5 required, open collapse and focus required element if empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39701894/html5-required-open-collapse-and-focus-required-element-if-empty)

I'm building in React and was able to hook to the `invalid` event listener by adding the following to my Input components:

```js
<Input onInvalid={this.showRequiredFields} />
```

Which triggered the visibility as needed!

Hope this helps, please let us know!

J